# Can you please proof that f is constant by computing the derivative f?

Tags: derivatives

Suppose that $│f(x) - f(y)│≤│x-y│^2$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

**Proof that $f$ is constant by computing the derivative $f$**

Comment: This just says that the derivative is bounded by 2.

Comment: @copper.hat : I think that is meant to be $|x-y|^2$

Comment: Shouldn't it be given that the function is differentiable?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: I think you are right.

Comment: [Duplicate 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537216/proving-a-function-is-constant-under-certain-conditions/537230#537230) and [Duplicate 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561780/math-analysis-differentiability?lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \left | \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\right | \leq \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|h|^2}{|h|} = 0
$$
Hence, $f' \equiv 0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** If $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x - y|^2$ for all real $x$ and $y$, then we have $-|x - y|^2 \leq f(x) - f(y)$ and $f(x) - f(y) \leq |x - y|^2$ for all real $x$ and $y$. Now the squeeze theorem states, roughly, that if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ and $g(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x) = \ell$ whenever $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = \ell$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}h(x) = \ell$. From the given inequalities, we obtain
$$ \frac{-|x - y|^2}{x - y} \leq \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \leq \frac{|x - y|^2}{x - y} \text{ for all } x \neq y $$
Now recall the definition of a derivative and consider the cases $x \geq a$ an $a > x$ to find the required limits. You should find that the middle limit is squeezed between two functions having $0$ as their limits as $x$ approaches $y$. These limits give the derivatives of the functions at the arbitrary point $y$.

Comment: that given inequalities are the limits yes?

Comment: No, they are the bounds on $|f(x) - f(y)|$.